# no module name pyodbc in aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, aws-lambda

Trying to connect my mssql with aws lambda  don't know how to install these libraries there

```
import json
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import pyodbc


def lambda_handler(event,context):
    s3=boto3.client('s3')
    if event:
        connection = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=adasdst-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433\SQLEXPRESS;' 'DATABASE=asd;''UID=asd;PWD=asd'
        conn = pyodbc.connect(connection)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print(conn)
```

error

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pyodbc'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

anykind of help will be appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and create a source_code directory.

`mkdir my_lambda_source`

`cd my_lambda_source`

Copy the contents of your code into `lambda_function.py`

```
import json 
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import pyodbc


def lambda_handler(event,context):
    s3=boto3.client('s3')
    if event:
        connection = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=adasdst-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433\SQLEXPRESS;' 'DATABASE=asd;''UID=asd;PWD=asd'
        conn = pyodbc.connect(connection)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        print(conn)
```

Install the required libraries to a new `package` directory.

`pip3 install --target ./package boto3`

`pip3 install --target ./package pyodbc`

If you are getting following errors while installing `pyodbc` then You need a driver manager. For Ubuntu run `sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev` on RedHat it would be `sudo yum install unixODBC-devel`

```
In file included from src/buffer.cpp:12:
src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
   56 | #include <sql.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

goto `package` directory zip your libraries into

```
zip -r ../my-deployment-package.zip .
```

This generates a `my-deployment-package.zip` file in your project directory `my_lambda_source`

Add the `lambda_function.py` file to the root of the zip file.

```
cd ..
zip -g my-deployment-package.zip lambda_function.py
```

Now upload `my-deployment-package.zip` file to lambda and test you code. It should work fine.

Refer.
[Creating a Lambda function with runtime dependencies.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html)

Comment: thanks deepak for your time had dropped the idea for using lambda but might help someone else

Answer (score 0):

Install the pyodbc package next to your module so that your script will be able to locate the dependency `python -m pip install --target ./ pyodbc`. Here is the AWS doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package-create.html See the section "Create a function with runtime dependencies".

Comment: i dont realy know how that zip method work but i tried it with the help of tutorial lemme add image where how my directory looks like

Comment: i have added the image please check

Comment: In the tutorial they install the dependency into a subfolder called `./package`, then they zip it, and then they add `lambda_function.py` to it. What you have is different, but will still work. You just have to zip your project up as it is. I would go to the parent directory of your project (i.e. not your project's root, but the one above that) then zip it.

Comment: it shows me the same error what i have done in image

Comment: should i zip it from site-packages ??? this is my previous directory which contain all these files

Comment: The idea is that your module's path will be added to `sys.path` when loaded by the interpreter. So the shared library for pyodbc needs to be next to your module in the zip file and both of those things should be at the top level. It looks like this is what you've done in the picture. I'm wondering if it could have something to do with a runtime mismatch??? It looks like you're using Windows, but the runtime for Python3 lambdas is Amazon Linux and pyodbc builds differently on Linux than on Windows. So even though you have the dynamic library right there, the Lambda runtime may not use it.

Comment: okay im geeting your point now  ,is there any solution for this if you know and thanks for the help

Comment: If it were me, I would try to make my development environment as much like the production environment as possible. I'd probably stand up a small Amazon Linux VM and do my work there, zip it, and put that artifact in Lambda.